# sql join by dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, join

I am currently using SQL Server 2016...

Need help writing a new query -

I have two tables - sales and employees.

Sales might look like:

[image]

The Employees table might look like:

[image]

I would like to call all rows from the sales table and bring in the supervisor field from the employees table - however, I need the supervisor field to join based on the date_to and date_from field in the employee table.  For example, this is what I would like my output to look like:

[image]

The supervisor and sales rep alignment would depend on the date in the sales table and where that date falls between the date_from and date_to fields in the employees table.  In this case since the first sale on 11/4 was between 1/1/2016 and 11/6/2016 - when we joined on sales_rep_id in the employees table, the supervisor would be Jim Jones.  However, the sale that occured on 11/15/16 falls between 11/7/2016 and 12/31/2999, which correlates to Tom Hall being the supervisor.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There is a comma missing in your code.

Comment: Specify which DBMS you are using

Comment: @EmilHolub SQL Server 2016

Comment: in future reference, instead of the pictures, give us a text format of the tables. You can do that in SSMS using the short-key CTRL+T. It speeds up the process. Oh, and pick the answer that solves your question.  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Setup:**

```
create table Sales
(
    sale_date DATE,
    sales_rep_name NVARCHAR(100),
    sales_rep_id INT,
)
GO

insert into Sales VALUES 
    ('20161004', 'Old man', 123),
    ('20161104', 'Smith, John', 12345), 
    ('20161115', 'Smith, John', 12345)
GO

create table Employees 
(
    sales_rep_name NVARCHAR(100),
    sales_rep_id INT,
    supervisor NVARCHAR(100),
    date_from DATE,
    date_to DATE
)
GO
```

**Testing:**

```
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES ('Smith, John', 12345, 'Jones, Jim', '20160101', '20160611'),
    ('Smith, John', 12345, 'Hall, Tom', '20160711', '99991231')
GO

-- gets all sales where INNER JOIN will go
-- even if LEFT JOIN is used, BETWEEN applied to NULL will rule out some records
SELECT S.sale_date, E.sales_rep_name, S.sales_rep_name, E.supervisor 
FROM Sales S
    JOIN Employees E ON S.sales_rep_id = E.sales_rep_id
         AND S.sale_date BETWEEN E.date_from and E.date_to
```

<strike>UNION ALL</strike>

```
-- just NULL the columns for the rest of the records
SELECT S.sale_date, NULL, S.sales_rep_name, NULL
FROM Sales S
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Employees E WHERE E.sales_rep_id = S.sales_rep_id AND S.sale_date BETWEEN E.date_from and E.date_to)
```

GO

Comment: Simply change `WHERE S.sale_date BETWEEN` to `AND S.sale_date BETWEEN` and there's no need for the `UNION`:)

Answer (score 1):

Your employee table is a so-called [Slowly Changing Dimension Type 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension#Type_2:_add_new_row), you need the BETWEEN as additional condition of an Outer Join:

```
SELECT *
FROM SALES AS sal
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEES AS emp
  ON sal.SALES_REP_ID = emp.SALES_REP_ID
 AND sal.DATE BETWEEN emp.DATE_FROM AND emp.DATE_TO
```

Don't put the BETWEEN in WHERE as this will turn the result into an Inner Join again.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a `LEFT JOIN`, just so you don't miss any sales.  Here is the right way to use it:

```
SELECT s.Date, e.sales_rep_name, s.sales_rep_id, e.supervisor
FROM sales s LEFT JOIN
     employees e
     ON s.sales_rep_id = e.sales_rep_id AND
        s.date >= e.date_from AND
        s.date <= e.date_to;
```

Note that the date conditions need to go in the `ON` clause for the `LEFT JOIN`.  Also, table aliases make it easier to write and to read the query.  If sales have no matches, then the information from `sales` will be in the result set with `NULL` values for the columns from `employees`.